# Why does the ouput is

Tags: c++, stack-memory

Why  does the output of this code is  0 10 10.dosnt the variable v without value in both the first and third cases?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void f(bool val)
{
    int v;
    if(val)v=10;
    cout<<v<<endl;

}
int main() {

    f(false);
    f(true);
    f(false);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ is probably not like languages you are used to. There are no variables without a value. It just so happens that you can't always know what the value is, or if it's safe to use.

Comment: if `val` is false, then print uninitialized `v` will lead to UB.

Answer (score 1):

Because when `val = false` this condition `if(val)` is not satisfied so the uninitialized variable `v` will be printed out.

At that time the value of `v` could be 0, the last value, or anything else. It's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`int v` just declares the `v` variable, but doesn't assign a value to it, so its value is undefined, it will be same as the current value in the memory.

you can assign `v` an initial value when declare, likes `int v = 0`, so when `val` is false, the `v` will be always `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer could vary as `x 10 x` where `x` can be any number. Actually, it's the garbage value. You will get its different value in different compiler on the different platform.

Somewhere you will get `0 10 10` because it buffers the value of v. but somewhere else will get `10 10 10` because it buffers the value at compile time. So, its not correct to say what will be the value of x.

So, you should say the **answer will be `x 10 x` where `x` is the garbage value.**

Comment: Not exactly so. The behavior is undefined so it might do anything.

Answer (score -3):

The answer will be 
10
10
10
You need to compare value of val in the if condition statement to get different answers. It is taking the value of v in the if statement because there is no comparison.
Try it some other Compilers.

try here
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: Always add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: The values could have been anything because it's undefined behavior. This shows nothing.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The OP is actually comparing `val` in the `if` statement

Comment: The condition of an if statement doesn't have to be a comparison. It can be anything that is or can be converted to a bool value.